# Why split a BizTalk solution into multiple projects

Tags: biztalk

I've read it's good practice to split a BizTalk solution into multiple projects, and have seen some debate as to the exact nature of the split, e.g. ...

 - could be split by artifact, i.e. Schemas, Orchestrations, Maps, etc.

 - could be split by function

But what's the benefits / con's  ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BizTalk solutions typically include schemas, maps, and orchestrations. Solutions can also include supporting components, Business Rules, definitions of port-based routing and transformations, trading partners, and several other types of artifacts.

Effectively managing all of these artifacts has many benefits – far more benefits than drawbacks.

The benefits include:

- Separation of concerns based on the
  logical grouping of artifacts (by
  functionality or artifact type for
  example). This approach reduces the
  possibility of modifying aspects of
  your solution that aren’t related to
  the problem you’re working on at the
  time.
- Easier to test – you can compile and
  deploy just the components you’re
  modifying.
- Easier to split work among a group of
  developers.
- Easier to manage when the solution
  gets larger – it can take several
  minutes to load large BizTalk
  solutions in Visual Studio.
- Supports more advanced approaches
  related to ESB-style solutions (very
  loose coupling). Depending on your
  overall approach, you can create a
  solution that is very modular – to
  the point that modules can operate
  and be updated completely
  independently of each other.
- Makes it possible to version
  artifacts separately.
- Facilitates more fine-grained control
  over security and memory utilization
  by grouping related functions such
  that you deploy them for a particular
  host instance, for example (you can
  also administer fine grained .NET
  security policies more easily than
  you can with a solution that deploys
  a few assemblies).

The main drawback to splitting your solution over several projects or solutions surfaces when you are debugging your solution. Debugging BizTalk solutions is not straightforward for many developers that are new to BizTalk and having to narrow-down bugs across solutions does not make the job any easier. However, you can mange this issue by more effectively arranging your solution and using standards around naming, directory structure, arrangement of namespaces, and related methods to make it easier to figure out where to look.

Other drawbacks include:

- More assemblies to sign and deploy
  into the GAC
- Inter-dependencies    between
  projects can result in    deployment
  errors that can be    difficult to
  track down in poorly    organized
  solutions.

You should dedicate some time at the beginning of a project – ideally during design – to setup the basic organization of your solution. A one-size-fits-all approach does not exist – you need to think about how you want to manage the solution during development, deployment and maintenance in the context of the functionality that the solution provides to your organization or clients.

A good place to start is to divide your solution based on artifact type or functional areas. As you grow your solution, you’ll get a better understanding about how artifacts relate to each other, how you want to manage strong naming, security, and physical deployment and be in a better position to arrange your solution more effectively. You need to be careful with this approach since you could end up having to rearrange large parts of the solution, which can be disruptive if your project’s timelines are tight.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response Erik, much appreciated