# Biztalk applications best practice

Tags: biztalk

Getting to grips with Biztalk, but still a newbie.  What is best practice on when and why to create a new application?
As way of an example I'm creating a connector which syncs between a CRM and a web based marketing tool.  I'll be polling the CRM and polling the webservice checking for updates in each to keep both in sync.  Should all this be deployed in 1 application with independent orchestrations running, or as 3 applications one for CRM one for the webservice, and one to reference the common schemas between both?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to organize the app along the lines of a Deployment Unit in both BizTalk Administrator and Visual Studio.

So, there would be a 1:1 relationship between the Solution and Application and your normal process would be to Deploy the entire Solution to the Application every time.

This also goes for how the Projects are organized.  For example, I'm not a huge fan of shared Schemas because of the Deployment obstacles.

Keep in mind though that BizTalk Server Standard Edition has a 5 Application Limit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is not straightforward.  See 
http://multishoring.info/corporate-news/biztalk-application-%E2%80%93-what-is-it/
[Biztalk Applications structure how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781720/biztalk-applications-structure-how-to)

Also in the excellent Pluralsight course **BizTalk Server 2013 from Ground Up: An End to End Scenario** the author MH separates EACH project (already split by business process / artefact into a separate Biztalk application.  For 1 'solution' there are ~20 separate Biztalk applications.

It seems logical to split by artefact in the VS solution, but then to deploy into a common Biztalk application, whereas deploying one application per project could quickly become unwieldy or impractical (especially as stated a 5 application limit).  Thoughts on the pros / cons of each method?

Comment: The Visual Studio Solution represents a single *functional App*.  Sure, divide the Projects by artifact type.  Deploy the entire Solution (all Projects) into one BizTalk Application.